# how to store x,y position of letter(of word) in 2D grid

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, hashtable

I want to store x,y position of my found word in a 2D grid(10x10 grid)

```
bonehwkcom
vurizleftl
edebaindex
ronlsgavth
twcixeorie
inakfzanch
cidrawkcab
aordnmawll
leuzsiqxak
eordsearch
wordsearch
```

Word bone found at: (0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (0,3). ***(This is what I want to store but don't know how)***

How would I store x and y as once the letter is validated?

*I need to store them because once I've found the word, I'll convert its lowercase letters to uppercase.*

I was thinking of saving it in an pointer *key. is there a better easier way?

Comment: @YSC Can't be C++ if that compiles, since `malloc` result isn't cast explicitly.

Comment: On the other hand, it doesn't compile either way. Please provide a [mre] of your problem. Copy-paste that code into the question. What you are showing clearly has typos.

Comment: It's written in C.

Comment: It is also not valid C code, `const char[] key = "a";` should be `const char key[] = "a";`

Answer (score 0):

One way

```
 // struct to hold co-ords
 struct cell{
      int x;
      int y;
 }
 ....
 char *foundWord = "bone";
 // create array of cell large enough for the word
 struct cell *wordLoc = malloc(sizeof(struct cell) * strlen(foundWord));
 ...
 // fill array 
 wordLoc[0].x = 0;
 wordLoc[0].y = 0;
 wordLoc[1].x = 0;
 wordLoc[1].y = 1;
```

etc